# How implements the Google Distance/Matrix Api at Android Studio?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm programming an app that calculates, in route, two locations. I've implemented the google places API to get the lat/lon based on name or address but I can't implement the Distance API. The classes/methods don't appear when I try to import. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```java
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
    private static final GeoApiContext context = new 
    GeoApiContext().setApiKey(API_KEY);


    public DistanceMatrix estimateRouteTime(DateTime time, Boolean isForCalculateArrivalTime, DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction routeRestriction, LatLng departure, LatLng... arrivals) {
        try {
            DistanceMatrixApiRequest req = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(context);
            if (isForCalculateArrivalTime) {
                req.departureTime(time);
            } else {
                req.arrivalTime(time);
            }
            if (routeRestriction == null) {
                routeRestriction = DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction.TOLLS;
            }
            DistanceMatrix trix = req.origins(departure)
                    .destinations(arrivals)
                    .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                    .avoid(routeRestriction)
                    .language("fr-FR")
                    .await();
            return trix;

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The GeoApiContext and DistanceMatrix don't appear at import.
Tks for help.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my question...

```
    public class GetJson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, DeliveryData> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // progressDialog 
    }

    @Override
    protected DeliveryData doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Utils util = new Utils();
        DeliveryData json = util.getInfo("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins="+latLngCompany.latitude+","+latLngCompany.longitude+
                "&destinations="+latPlace+","+lonPlace+"&key=" + APISERVERKEY);
        deliveryData.saveDeliveryData();

        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DeliveryData deliveryData) {
        //progressDialog.dismiss
    }
}
```

Created a AsyncTask to get json from url with the especifics parameters.

```
public class Utils {

public DeliveryData getInfo(String end){

    String json;
    DeliveryData output;
    json = NetworkUtils.getJSONFromAPI(end);
    output = parseJson(json);


    return output;
}

private DeliveryData parseJson(String json){
    try {
        DeliveryData deliveryData = new DeliveryData();

        JSONObject distanceJson = new JSONObject(json)
                .getJSONArray("rows")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray("elements")
                .getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("distance");
        Double distanceDouble = null ;
        String distance = distanceJson.get("text").toString();
        if (distance.contains("km")){
            distanceDouble = Double.parseDouble(distance.replace("km", ""));

        }else {
            distanceDouble = Double.parseDouble("0." + distance.replace("m", ""));
        }

        deliveryData.setDistance(distanceDouble);

        return deliveryData;
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

At getInfo, the data from url is passed to string. Then, parseJson is call to transform the string to JsonObject.
My Json there is only one position. So, the object is selected at array and the String is parse to Double, excluding the chars. In the end, the distance is saved at object.

```
public class NetworkUtils {

public static String getJSONFromAPI (String url){
    String output = "";
        try {
            URL apiEnd = new URL(url);
            int responseCode;
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            InputStream is;

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) apiEnd.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST){
                is = connection.getInputStream();
            }else {
                is = connection.getErrorStream();
            }

            output = convertISToString(is);
            is.close();
            connection.disconnect();

        }  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return output;
}

private static String convertISToString(InputStream is){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        BufferedReader br;
        String row;

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((row = br.readLine())!= null){
            buffer.append(row);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

This class is resposible for connecting to server and get the data from url.